# Get the "value" attribute of an option in a <select> with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I am trying to get the "value" attribute in an  tag (inside a  tag.

My current code:

JavaScript:

```
var TheId = $('.nameofselect option:selected').val();
```

HTML:

```
<option value="123">Text value</option>
```

But this is returning the "Text value" of the option, not the actual value (i.e. 123) - which is what I need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hat should work, although you don't need `option:selected`. Just `$('.classofselect').val()`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4ApJy/1/ Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Do you have `class="nameofselect"` in the `<select>` element?

Comment: @Barmar If it don't have that class then how it would have returned `Text value`... Quite confusing..

Comment: I don't know. He must have done something wrong, and he didn't copy it to the question.

Comment: I suspect he has a typo in `value="123"`. If there's no `value` attribute, the default is to use the text content.

Comment: @Barmar, I think you might be right. In my php code i have it echoing the ID of the row in <option value="  here  ">, but when I look at the source code it is showing another columns value. Ill fix that and see what happens

Comment: @JordanS—the HTML you post here **must** be what the client gets, not what you *think* PHP is generating.

Comment: Ok, something weird is happening. No matter what I put in the <option value="">, what ever is in-between the <option> opening tab and closing </option> tag is being used as the value and the display text

Comment: Don't worry, I've found the issue. Another function I have running is stuffing things up. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.val()` to get selected `value` of `select` tag :

```
var TheId = $('.nameofselect').val();
```

And if you want to read value attribute of option then use below :

```
$('.nameofselect option').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: The jQuery *val* method does not necessarily return the value of the *value* attribute. It returns the attribute if present, or the text content of the option if there is no value attribute. If you want the actual value of an option's value attribute, use `option.getAttribute('value')`, or the jQuery *attr* method (in versions after 1.6).

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar You don't need to use `.each()` jQuery will iterate the result set without it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()` selector

Try this

```
$('.nameofselect option:selected').attr('value'); // Return 123

$('.nameofselect').val() // Return 123
```

Example HTML

```
<select class="nameofselect">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="123">Text value</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$('.nameofselect').on('change',function(){
   alert( $(this).find('option:selected').val())
   alert( $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'))
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n9rLF/6/)

Comment: When I try the $('.nameofselect').val(), it says undefined. When I change it to $('#idofselect').val() it displays the text value, not the ID that I want

Comment: Not my downvote, but `$(this).find('option:selected').val()` is just a crazily inefficient way to do `this.value`.

Comment: RobG OP said in that way it shows undefined thats why we answered like that we too know this.value will reurn

Comment: The point is that all that jQuery does nothing useful except burn CPU cycles. Direct access to the DOM property removes jQuery as a factor (and is hugely faster and less to type).